# Javascript: how to get selected option value that is in the datalist with inside select

Tags: javascript, html

On this below code, Am trying to get the value of selected 'option' from 'select' element that is in the 'datalist' element. Have tried something, but, i couldn't. Am expecting solution only in javascript. As of now, it always alerts the first option value however we change the option value. It should alert actual option value when i change the option value on the input box. For example if i select 'Blueberry' then it should omit 'Bluberry'.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML 5 test Elements</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <label>Your favorite fruit:
                <datalist id="fruit">
                    <select name="fruits">
                        <option value="Blackberry">Blacskberry</option>
                        <option value="Blackcurrant">Blackcurrant</option>
                        <option value="Blueberry">Blueberry</option>
                    </select>
                    If other, please specify:
                </datalist>
                <input type="text" name="fruit" list="fruit"/>
            </label>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                document.getElementsByName("fruit")[0].onchange = function (event) {
                    var evt = event || window.event;
                    var parElem = evt.srcElement || evt.target;
                    alert(document.getElementsByName("fruits")[0].options[document.getElementsByName("fruits")[0].selectedIndex].value);
                }
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any idea? please.

Comment: what is exact issue code working well return selected index of datalist select value

Comment: Careful using the datalist element http://caniuse.com/#search=datalist

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can remove `<select>` element and just keep the `<datalist>` and its nested `<options>`. Just use the datalist. Then you can use the `input` event to check for a change on the `<input>` which is connected to the datalist

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bkab62rq/

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to get the alert only if the one of the preset values is used try following:

```
<html>
  <head>
      <title>HTML 5 test Elements</title>
  </head>
  <body>
              <div>
        <label>Your favorite fruit:
            <datalist id="fruit">
                <select id="fruits">
                    <option value="Blackberry">Blacskberry</option>
                    <option value="Blackcurrant">Blackcurrant</option>
                    <option value="Blueberry">Blueberry</option>
                </select>
                If other, please specify:
            </datalist>
            <input type="text" name="fruit" list="fruit"/>
        </label>                  
      <script type="text/javascript">
         document.getElementsByName("fruit")[0].onchange = function (event) {
                var evt = event || window.event;
                var parElem = evt.srcElement || evt.target;                             
                for (var i=0; i<document.getElementById('fruits').options.length; i++)
                { 
                    if (document.getElementById('fruits').options[i].value ==  document.getElementsByName("fruit")[0].value) 
                    { 
                      alert(document.getElementById('fruits').options[i].value);
                      break;
                    }                                                
               }
            }
      </script></div></body></html>
```

This should do the Magic ;)

Here you got an Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/16e8qanz/19/

This should work

Greetz Anders

Comment: Please upvote or accept if this is working, otherwise, please specify the problem :)